# pip による google-api-python-client のインストールで Could not find a version というエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, google-api, pip

python初心者です。pythonからBigqueryを動かしたくて
下記packageインストールしようとしていますが、

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-api-python-client (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-api-python-client
```

でも

```
$ pip install bigquery-python

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bigquery-python 
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bigquery-python
```

同じエラーが出てインストールできないです。何が問題なのでしょうか。

バージョン情報：

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)

$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from (python 3.6)
```

Comment: とりあえず `pip -V` の結果とOSの情報が要るでしょうか。

Comment: 参考までに、手元の環境は `python 3.6.2/pip 9.0.1(python3.6)` ですが、`google-api-python-client` と `bigquery-python` を問題なくインストールすることができました。

Comment: これは不思議ですね。 `pip -v search google-api-python-client` などでも、pypiへのアクセスの経過でエラーになったりするのでしょうか。

Comment: `pip -v install --upgrade google-api-python-client` を実行した結果を追記してみてください。どこにパッケージを探しに行っているかログが表示されるので、それをそのまま貼り付けお願いします。